# Track results of a regular expression extractor in JMeter

Tags: regex, http-headers, jmeter

Our server returns a custom 'X-Execution-Time' HTTP response header that returns in miliseconds the time between the server getting a request and our code returning a page, ie how long our code takes to run.  I'm using JMeter to do some testing & I'd like to be able to report on this number of over time.  I've setup this regular expression extractor: `X-Execution-Time:\s(\d+)` but I don't know how to get JMeter to report on this number per request so i can get a trend over time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't elegant by any means, but it certainly works:

Add a debug sampler into your test plan, and give it the same name as your regex reference.  This will write out the time value into the results file.

Example if you have different pages:

regex reference = X-Execution-Time
Debug Sampler Name = PageName - Execution: ${X-Execution-Time}