# JMeter repeat Regular Expression extractor for all requests

Tags: regex, jmeter, extractor

I have a JMeter script that goes through a bunch of requests, each being different, GETs, POSTs and so on...

Each request returns a custom header from the server that has some numeric values in it. This header returns the actual processing time it took on the server side (without latency/http overhead)

I was able to add a Regular Expression Extractor to get that value from the header without any problems, however I would like this to be repeated for all the requests.

By using Debug Sampler I can see that the extractor only runs once, seems to be the last instance.

How can I have an extractor that runs all all requests and collects all the values from the header.

Bonus question. Finally I would love to be able to aggregate these values and get one average value.

Disclaimer: This other question is similar to mine but it doesn't explain how to actually do it in terms of the locations of the extractor and the debug sampler.

[Track results of a regular expression extractor in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535078/track-results-of-a-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Dmitri's answer is one way of doing it. But I wanted something different than each time exporting it into a file and post processing it...

I ended up doing this "manually"

By manually I mean I added a BSF Assertion with language = JavaScript and then wrote some JavaScript to do this:

1. Pull the value out of the header (if found)
2. Keep a record of total/count using variables
3. Updating a variable that shows the aggregate always
4. Add Debug Sampler to get easy access to the values after the test.

The following is the code that I used in the BSF Assertion:

```
var responseHeaders = prev.getResponseHeaders();

var xNodetasticRt = /x-nodetastic-rt: (\d+\.?\d*)/.exec(responseHeaders);

if (xNodetasticRt) {
    var value = parseFloat(xNodetasticRt[1]);

    vars.put("xNodetasticRt", value); 

    var total = parseFloat(vars.get("xNodetasticRt-Total")); 
    if (!total) {
        total = 0.0;
    }
    total += value;
    vars.put("xNodetasticRt-Total", total);

    var count = parseFloat(vars.get("xNodetasticRt-Count")); 
    if (!count) {
        count = 0;
    }
    count++;
    vars.put("xNodetasticRt-Count", count);

    vars.put("xNodetasticRt-Average", total / count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put Regular Expression Extractor at the same level as your HTTP Request samplers and it will be applied to all of them

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor]

See [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) User Manual entry for more detailed explanation.

With regards to value collection the best option is using [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property. Given you store your header value into a variable called `${foo}` you can get it appended to jtl results file by adding the next line to the *user.properties* file:

```
sample_variables=foo
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up. The other way (which doesn't require restart) is passing the property via `-J` command-line argument as

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=foo -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

As the result you will get an extra column called `foo` in the .jtl results file and it will hold the `${foo}` variable value for each Sampler. Upon test completion you will be able to open .jtl results file with MS Excel or equivalent and use [AVERAGE](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/AVERAGE-function-047bac88-d466-426c-a32b-8f33eb960cf6) function to get the value you're looking for.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on setting and amending various JMeter properties for [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) according to your needs.